# Posting question applicable for 2 communities

Tags: support, site-crossover, cross-posting

I have this question I posted at the Game Development Community.

[Compressing language for Game use to save Packets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98167/compressing-language-for-game-use-to-save-packets)

Although the question is related to game development, I feel I can get more answer if I link or re-post the question at Stack Overflow. What's the proper thing to do?